# Wrong colors in vim over ssh

Tags: vim, ssh, iterm2

I have OSX Yosemite with iTerm2. I connect via ssh to my virtual machine with Debian 8. When I run vim all colors are messed up.

iTerm2 has xterm-256colors on.

Comment: What is your terminal on the Debian system? `echo $TERM` will tell you.

Comment: it's "xterm-256color"

Answer (score 14):

A number of things can affect your Vim colorscheme.

Make sure iTerm has the terminal type correct. As you indicated already, you use `xterm-256color`.

Make sure your remote shell has a matching terminal type, which you can verify with `echo $TERM`. If it is not set already, configure your shell with something like

```
# For sh, bash, zsh, ksh
export TERM=xterm-256color

# For csh, tcsh
setenv TERM xterm-256color
```

If the color scheme you are trying to use assumes that 256-color support is available, you may also need to add to your `.vimrc`:

```
set t_Co=256
```

Lastly, color schemes can be affected by the `background` setting in Vim, which you can set to either `dark` or `light`. To see what it's set to,

```
:set background?
```

And to set it one way or the other in your `.vimrc`,

```
set background=dark
```

(or `light`).

Comment: I use scheme "desert", if I echo t_Co in vim it says 256, setting background seem to have no effect :(

Comment: You still need to set `$TERM` to a 256-capable terminal on the remote shell.  `export TERM=xterm-256color` for example. (set permanently in .bashrc on the remote machine)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski True, however the OP noted in comments on the question that this is already the case. But I will include it in my answer for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @DanLowe I missed that in the comments

Comment: This worked for me in Win 10 powershell as well, if someone is wondering.

Comment: background was the key for me.

Comment: I had to change the background to dark in order for gruvbox to work over ssh (it had a desert/tan/beige) background prior to that.

Comment: Over ssh with `TERM=rxvt-unicode-256color` and without `set background=dark`, I see (over a slow connection) vim first paint with my t_Co=256 theme, but then immediately repaint with t_Co set to some smaller value. Adding background=dark eliminates the repaint and my "wrong" colors.  (or maybe there are still two repaints but t_Co stays the same)  It would be nice to understand why ...